# problem with visual studio code in syntax

Tags: html

I am a beginner in programming learning and I have a problem writing the code on Visual Studio. When I press the tap button to format and save, what you have modified using the tap button is canceled. Please solve it as soon as possible and thank you in advance.

Comment: When you press `tab` on your keyboard, code takes the first suggestion from the drop down list that is shown to you.

Answer (score 0):

If you referring to formatting the code, i suggesting you to use an extension called **Prettier**, it makes your code better by formatting it automatically for you, you can navigate to **Extensions** tab on the left sidebar then write on the search box "*Prettier*" install it then reload the application and it will work.

**How to use:** Just write the code and save it (CTRL + S) then Prettier will automatically formatting the code for you.

Comment: thanks for the help i found the problem because you the problem was in extension